# How to convert HttpResponse of contentType text/html to JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, httprequest

Below is the response I am getting from `HttpRequest`. I want to return this response in JSON to Ajax request from spring controller.

```
({
   'KUI': {
       code: '.KUI',
       indexDetailEnable: true,
       price: '20,650.21',
       netChange: '-13.01',
       percentChange: '-0.06％',
       tradeDate: '17/04/03',
       tradeTime: '16:50',
       chartDate: '17/04/03',
       chartTime: '16:50'
    },

   'KUI': {
       code: '.NHK',
       indexDetailEnable: true,
       price: '--',
       netChange: '--',
       percentChange: '--％',
       tradeDate: '--/--/--',
       tradeTime: '--:--',
       chartDate: '17/04/03',
       chartTime: '17:15'
    },

    __end__: null
});
```

Comment: This is already in JSON except the brackets.

Comment: @CicilThomas I tried to print using jsonprettyprint but it printing null. {
  "abc": "abc"
} I think this is the json format.

Comment: @CicilThomas I have removed ( ) and semicolon before printing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In JSON a name/value pair consists of a field name (in double quotes), followed by a colon, followed by a value( via w3School). The keys of above response are not enclosed in " ". So how come above response is already in JSON? May be I am missing something.

Comment: Yes you are correct, a valid JSON keys and values should be enclosed in double qoutes. Try Gson.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `new JSONObject(yourResponse)` or `new JSONArray(youResponse)` from org.json